# IoC and Unity, where do I call the method that registers the types

Tags: c#, web-services, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I try to learn and use the IoC together with Unity in web services but I can't figure out how to or what should call the method that calls all the registerType methods.

In pseudo code I will try to clarify my question.

```
[WebMethod]
public void DoSomething()
{
    var obj = IoC.Resolve<ISomeInterface>();
    obj.Container.DoSomething();
}

interface ISomeInterface
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public class SomeClass : ISomeInterface
{
    pulic void DoSomething()
    {
        //do something here
    }
}

public static class IoC
{
    public static IUnityContainer Container = new UnityContainer();

    public static void Init()
    {
        container.RegisterType<ISomeInterface, SomeClass>();
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how or what should call the method Init() in the example above. I try to do this in a project I created by following the next steps. I create a new Empty ASP.NET Web Application in Visual Studio 2012. Then I add a Web Service item to it and in the .asmx.cs file is my webmethod. The webservice will be called by AJAX in JavaScript.

What do I need to do so the webservice will call the Init Method when it starts?

Comment: I think there's some kind of "Startup" event for webservices, but I don't remember what it's called or where it's set. (very helpful, I know) Beyond that, why not have the initialization in the static constructor for `IoC` so it's performed before the `Container` field is first accessed? EDIT: Added bonus is you can't call `Init` multiple times and mess things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just perform the registration in the IoC's static constructor so it's automatically performed before/when you hit the `Container` field for the first time:

```
public static class IoC
{
    public static readonly IUnityContainer Container;

    static IoC()
    {
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<ISomeInterface, SomeClass>();
        Container = container;
    }
}
```